# What SSH server should send to the client as a response to user pressing backspace?

Tags: java, ssh, terminal, terminal-emulator

I'm writing a simple service based on [Apache MINA sshd](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/).

While testing on Windows with Putty I implemented backspace (ASCII 127) handling by sending it back and removing last character from local command buffer.

But this approach does not seem to work with Secure Shell Chrome extension. The last char stays on the screen. I tried sending a ' ' to overwrite it but the carriage advances and the client ends up with an extra space.

Not sure what standards govern that behavior, I only found [transport layer RFC 4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253) that does not seem to cover that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. The SSH server should not intermediate in any way between the client and whatever the client is connected to.

Comment: I see. I think I got it now. The keyword I was looking for is "xterm" because the server is also doing that part of the work. I'm using Putty as a UI to my service.